# How we can change the $e^{x}$ in to Meijer G function?

Tags: exponential-function

I am new in this group, learning about Meijer G-Function, but I didn't understand, how could I change into $e^{x}$ into G-Function?

$$ e^{x} = G^{1, 0}_{0, 1}\left({\frac {{-}}{{0}}}\, \Big\vert\,^{}_{-x}\right)$$
where $G$ is the Meijer G function.

Comment: Which definition of the function do you want to use ?

Comment: Write out the G-function as a contour integral according to its definition. Prove that the residue theorem applies and use the fact that $\operatorname{Res}_{s = k} \Gamma(-s) = (-1)^{k + 1}/k!$ for $k \in \mathbb N^0$.